# Else-If branch in VB6

Tags: vba, vb6

I have written the following code :

```
    If s_Temp3 Then 

            sdbname = s_Temp3

    ElseIf Not IsEmpty(s_Temp1)

            sdbname = s_Temp1

    Else 

            sdbname = s_Temp2

    End If

End If
```

When I try to compile, it gives me a syntax error on the line with `ElseIf Not IsEmpty(s_Temp1)` and I don't know why.

Does anyone know what's the problem? Thanks

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243382(v=vs.60).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `Then` at the end of that line:

```
ElseIf Not IsEmpty(s_Temp1) Then
```

In more detail, following your clarification, you need

```
 If s_Temp3 Then     
     sdbname = s_Temp3    
 Else
     If Not IsEmpty(s_Temp1) Then    
         sdbname = s_Temp1    
     Else     
         sdbname = s_Temp2    
     End If    
 End If
```

Comment: Thanks! I solved that one but now it gives a syntax error at the last line of the code (at the last End If)

Comment: I'm not sure that it is errant. This is what the code should do http://i.imgur.com/EqnOKV1.png